# Angular 5 HttpClient.put executes two requests

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest, frontend, put

I'm building PWA with Angular 5. And having problem with duplicated execution of PUT requests. I'm also running POST and GET requests but this bug appears only with PUT.

This is the method

```
put(url: string, data: string): Observable<any> {
  console.log('put');
  const options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    })
  };
  return this.http
    .put(url, data, options).map(resp => {
      console.log('put_output');
      return resp;
    });
}
```

It makes two requests when this method runs only once.

Network tab screenshot:
[image: Network tab screenshot]

Console output screenshot:
[image: Console output screenshot]

I've tried to run simple XMLHttpRequest and it was perfect: one request, one response.

Answer (score 0):

The first request is a [**Preflighted Request**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests), this behavior is OK, and some developers call it *"Handshake with server"*.

From DOCS:

> "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS
>   method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine
>   whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are
>   preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.

You can also check the issue [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13033).

Comment: The thing is that this is not cross domain request. First one is not OPTIONS request. Requests are simmilar. Both of them are PUT, has simmilar body and response.